# make jQuery Growl plugin messages not fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, growl

I am using jQuery Growl plugin to notify messages to my users in my web site,
my messages displayTimeout is 3500, my problem is that some of the notifications messages need to fade after displayTimeout but some needs to stay static until i will remove them.
my question is how i make my notifications stay and not fade out?
thanks

Comment: Please, don't leave us guessing, show some code.

Answer (score 2):

this cycle is responsible for showing and fading.. you may edit the code..

```
Growl.prototype.cycle = function() {
    var $growl;
    $growl = this.$growl();
    console.log(this.settings.duration);
    return enter code here$growl.queue(this.present).delay(this.settings.duration).queue(this.dismiss).queue(this.remove);
    };
```

make it like this..

```
Growl.prototype.cycle = function() {
      var $growl;
      $growl = this.$growl();
      console.log(this.settings.duration);
      if(this.settings.duration==0){
            return $growl.queue(this.present);
      }else{
            return $growl.queue(this.present).delay(this.settings.duration).queue(this.dismiss).queue(this.remove);
      }
    };
```

so if you initialize like this..

```
$.growl({
                title: "Saving",
                style: "primary",
                message: 'Please wait...',
                duration: 0
            });
```

it wont fade out.. you might want to fade it manually using "dismiss"

Comment: It will fade out after mouse over, so it seems that there is more to set that this.
However setting duration to some abstract high value would make the trick.

Comment: It is fading after some abstract high value. I gave (123123123123). What value did you give @9ilsdx9rvj0lo

Answer (score 1):

In jquery.growl.js file just comment this lines of code:

```
if ($.growl.settings.displayTimeout > 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery.growl.settings.noticeRemove(notice, function(){
                notice.remove();
            });
        }, jQuery.growl.settings.displayTimeout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it trought using Growl.settings.duration = duration;

My function I created:

```
function woobe_message(text, type, duration = 0) {
    jQuery('.growl').hide();
    if (duration > 0) {
        Growl.settings.duration = duration;
    }
    switch (type) {
        case 'notice':
            jQuery.growl.notice({message: text});
            break;

        case 'warning':
            jQuery.growl.warning({message: text});
            break;

        case 'clean':
            //clean
            break;

        default:
            jQuery.growl({title: '', message: text});
            break;
}

}
```